# How to get Bytes from swift Data

Tags: ios, swift

in my app I've to create some packet to send directly via network to an external device. I'm trying to create the packet.
In Objective-C I made something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"0021";
NSData *lengthData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
[data appendBytes:[lengthData bytes] length:[lengthData length]];
```

so in swift I made something like this:

```
let string = "0021"
let lengthData = string.data(using: String.Encoding.nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: false)
data.append(lengthData?.bytes, count: pkt.length)
```

but the compiler says `Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<UInt8>'`, can someone help me to fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift you can just append the data (assuming `data` is `Data` and `var`)

```
if let lengthData = string.data(using: .nonLossyASCII) {
    data.append(lengthData)
}
```